# How do I make text boxes that are stacking and right and left justified?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to simulate a cell phone text conversation with text on the right and left, but not beside each other. I want them to look like messages popping up one after another.

I tried writing this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

def text_message(answer1, answer2):
    """This will hopefully show in text boxes text messages back and forth"""

    root = Tk()
    frame = Frame(root, bg='white')
    frame.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
    root.title("Uganda Project")
    T = Text(frame, height=3, width=35)
    T.pack(side=RIGHT)
    T.insert(END, "Did you take your medicine today?\nin 1= Yes\nin 2= No\n")
    T.configure(fg='white', bg='blue')
    root.mainloop()
    for answer in answer1:
        frame2 = Frame(root, bg='white')
        frame2.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
        T2 = Text(frame2, height=1, width=5)
        T2.pack(side=LEFT)
        T2.insert(END, answer1)
        T2.configure(fg='black', bg='lightgray')
        if answer==1:
            frame3 = Frame(root, bg='white')
            frame3.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
            T3 = Text(frame3, height=1, width=12)
            T3.pack(side=RIGHT)
            T3.insert(END, "Good Job!")
            T3.configure(fg='white', bg='blue')
        else:
            frame3 = Frame(root, bg='white')
            frame3.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
            T3 = Text(frame3, height=3, width=32)
            T3.pack(side=RIGHT)
            T3.insert(END, "1= Did you forget?\nin 2= Did you run out of medicine?\nin 3= Did it have bad side effects?\n")
            T3.configure(fg='white', bg='blue')
    for answer in answer2:
        frame4 = Frame(root, bg='white')
        frame4.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
        T4 = Text(frame4, height=1, width=5)
        T4.pack(side=LEFT)
        T4.insert(END, answer1)
        T4.configure(fg='black', bg='lightgray')
        if answer==1:
            frame5 = Frame(root, bg='white')
            frame5.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
            T5 = Text(frame5, height=2, width=36)
            T5.pack(side=RIGHT)
            T5.insert(END, "Take it as your earliest convience.\nin Do Not Take two doses at once!\n")
            T5.configure(fg='white', bg='blue')
        elif answer==2:
            frame5 = Frame(root, bg='white')
            frame5.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
            T5 = Text(frame5, height=1, width=52)
            T5.pack(side=RIGHT)
            T5.insert(END, "Please contact your doctor or pharmacy for refills.\n")
            T5.configure(fg='white', bg='blue')
        else:
            frame5 = Frame(root, bg='white')
            frame5.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
            T5 = Text(frame5, height=3, width=35)
            T5.pack(side=RIGHT)
            T5.insert(END, "Please contact your doctor about\nin changing your medications or\nin dealing with your symptoms.\n")
            T5.configure(fg='white', bg='blue')
    text_message(2,3)
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! I can't give you specific help, but the best way to find the root of the issue is to construct an [mcve]. If you can identify 10 or fewer lines of code that cause the issue, you'll be much closer to solving it. If you get stuck at that point, having shorter code would also help others see the problem, too.

Comment: Nothing under `root.mainloop` will run until _after_ your GUI is destroyed. Upon which you'll get error(s).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, *remove*:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

as you're *never* using it.

---

Secondly, remove:

```
root.mainloop()
```

and add:

```
from tkinter import * # this is here only to show indentation level
...
mainloop()
```

as *the very last* line in the outermost scope, so that it no longer blocks the expressions underneath.

---

Thirdly, move the call of your method to the main-body of the script. Remove:

```
text_message(2,3)
```

and put:

```
from tkinter import * # this is here only to show indentation level
...
text_message(2,3)
```

---

Then, run your code and read the errors which you can fix by replacing:

```
for answer in answer1:
...
for answer in answer2:
```

with:

```
for answer in range(answer1):
...
for answer in range(answer2):
```

And voilà you should have what you wanted.

---

To answer the general question of:

> *"How to display widgets stacked while being right or left justified?"*

I believe your approach of, encapsulating the widget in a frame that expands and fills, while stacking the widget to the right or left(justification part) *in* the frame, is a good one.